# How to determine required difference for significance in R

Tags: r, p-value

I wrote a small script that generates a distribution with mean `m1` and a second distribution with mean `m2`, where `m2` is in the vicinity `diff` of `m1`.

```
m1   <- 2.50
diff <- 0.1
m2   <- seq(m1 - diff, m1 + diff, by=diff/15)
nsamples    <- 250

d <- data.frame("m1"=rep(m1, length(m2)), "m2"=m2, "pv"=rep(0, length(m1)))

for(i in 1:nrow(d)) {
    d$pv[i] <- d$pv[i] + t.test(
     rnorm(n=nsamples, mean=d$m1[i], sd=0.1)-rnorm(n=nsamples, mean=d$m2[i], sd=0.1)
           )$p.value
}
```

I'm interested now in how the p-value behaves depending on `diff` and `nsamples`, so I plotted it for the given parameters:

[image]

Am I interpreting correctly (i.e. does my code do the right thing?) that from `diff` around 2.455 and 2.555 the p-value reaches significance?

If its not too unrelated, is the way I'm setting up the `d` data.frame to accumulate the p-values done in a good way? Do I really have to prepare the `m1` column with all the same value 2.5 in advance?

Comment: aside from your question, remember to correct for [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction).

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified at many points. I'll go them trough step by step.

```
m1   <- 2.50
diff <- 0.1
m2   <- seq(m1 - diff, m1 + diff, by=diff/15)
```

If you plug in `m1` and `diff` you get `m2 <- seq(2.4, 2.6, by = 0.1/15)`. I generaly prefer using `length` instead of `by` as long as you don't net this exact stepwidth (and your question doesn't gives the Impression that this is the case). So I would write `m2 <- seq(2.4, 2.6, length = 31)`.

```
nsamples <- 250 # is fine.

d <- data.frame("m1"=rep(m1, length(m2)), "m2"=m2, "pv"=rep(0, length(m1))) # if you are only interesered in the plot shown, you don't need a data.frame.
```

About the loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(d)) {
  d$pv[i] <- d$pv[i] + t.test(
   rnorm(n=nsamples, mean=d$m1[i], sd=0.1)-rnorm(n=nsamples, mean=d$m2[i], sd=0.1)
       )$p.value
}
```

The Expression `d$pv[i] <- d$pv[i] + t.test(...)` is futile as you initialise `d$pv[i]` with `0`, so you calculate `d$pv[i] <- 0 + t.test(...)`. Just write `d$pv[i] <- t.test(...)`.

Instead of building the difference from two independent normal variable draws, you can draw from the distribution of the differences: `rnorm(n = nsamples, mean = d$m1[i] - d$m2[i], sd = sqrt(0.1^2 + 0.1^2))`. If we recapitulate what `d$m1` and `d$m2` is we see that `d$m1[i] - d$m2[i]` is `2.5 - seq(2.4, 2.6, length = 31)` which is nothing else than `seq(-0.1, 0.1, length = 31)`.

So what I would do is the following:

```
nsamples <- 250
diff <- 0.1
new <- seq(-diff , diff, length = 31)
p <- array(dim = length(new))
for(i in 1:length(new)) {
  p[i] <- t.test(rnorm(n=nsamples, mean = new[i], sd = sqrt(2)/10))$p.value
}
plot(x = new, y = p, type = "l")
```

---

Edit 2016-08-26 after request in comments:
When one wants to avoid the loop, one could use `sapply`:

```
p <- sapply(new, function(x) t.test(rnorm(n=nsamples, mean = x, sd = sqrt(2)/10))$p.value)
```

Comment: good points. Is there a way to avoid the for loop? I ask because many operations in R are vectorized, so I wonder if I can use this.

Comment: @TMOTTM, yes - see update (it is `p <- sapply(new, function(x) t.test(rnorm(n=nsamples, mean = x, sd = sqrt(2)/10))$p.value)`).